# Crystal report with multiple image on same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I correctly imported an image on my CR using C#. Now I need to show a report with 4 different product on same page, something like that:

---

### | P1 | P2 |

### | P3 | P4 |

To do that I create a report and changed the option Repeat on Horizontal Pages to true but I still can see a single image for every page.

Where can I found a tutorial or a sample to do that?

many thanks,

Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use multiple columns in your report.

1. Open the report you want to format with multiple columns.
2. On the Report menu, click Section Expert.
   Tip: Another way to do this is to click the Section Expert button on the Expert Tools toolbar.
3. In the Section Expert, highlight Details, and then select Format with Multiple Columns.
   A Layout tab is added to the Section Expert.
4. Click the Layout tab and set the Width you want your column to be.
   Keep in mind the width of your paper when deciding your column width. For example, if you have three fields in your Details section, and they take up four inches of space, limit the width of the column to under four and a half inches so that all the field information can be seen.
5. Set the Horizontal and/or Vertical gap you want to maintain between each record in your column.
6. In the Printing Direction area, choose a direction.
7. If the report you're formatting contains grouping, select Format Groups with multiple column.
8. Click OK.

Comment: This is taken directly from Crystal Help.